# iPhone WebApp not working properly after adding to home screen

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile-safari, html-framework-7

Before I present the issue, I think it's important to tell you that I'm not an iPhone user and have little knowledge on how to operate with one. That being said, here's the issue we are facing: We have this web app that works fine on all major smartphone's browsers. Recently we figured that Chrome and Safari lets you add web sites to the home screen. The end result is like a hybrid app with no browser URL and all. On Safari, though, we noticed that weird things happens. Some features just don't work and sometimes, caching doesn't recycle even after clearing it. We also tried to remove the icon and create it again, but that didn't solve the issue...

My question is: Is there an interface to "communicate" with this "hybrid app"?

If somehow Safari keeps logs or any relevant information regarding this icon-to-home-screen feature, it would help greatly understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If by "communicate" you mean inspect html content and debug javascript code, then you can enable the Web Inspector and use Safari on your Mac to do so.

Here are the instructions: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

Comment: Would that work for that "hybrid app" pinned to the home screen too?

Comment: Yes, you can inspect any Safari instance on your iphone.